# Add "self answers can't earn populist badge" rule to populist badge description (and venting)

Tags: discussion, badges, populist-badge

I've been wondering why I didn't earn a Populist badge for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495908/205192) and only after digging through meta did I find that there's actually an extra rule, not documented on the badge page, that [self answers don't qualify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119221/161346).

I don't actually expect the rule to change, but I think it'd be fair to mention it in the badge description.  In my case, I wouldn't have been happily waiting for a badge that was never to come.

/vent on

And I also want to vent a little bit here.  In my case, the answer I accepted was written [*by the guy who wrote the control in question*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy).  Folks happened to like my answer better, but his is clearly the correct one with regards to the question asked and I thought it only fair to accept it.  I know the rule is to prevent gaming the system, but it's just a bit comical how clearly that is not the case here!  Arg! ;)

/vent off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've gone ahead and added that tidbit of information to the big [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258) page, which is where we try to keep all the smallest details of every badge.

That particular badge description is long enough without the need to add *more* to it. Also, they don't really list all the tiny details for every badge. For example, the editing badges have tons of other details not mentioned in the badge description itself.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Was really just looking for some commiseration anyway :P