# Can down-votes cause badge-loss?

Tags: support, badges, voting, down-votes

If I down-vote an answer that currently has a score of 10, 25 or 100, does the user lose his "nice answer", "good answer" or "great answer" badge?

Comment: No, regular badges are permanent (though tag badges are not).

Comment: They are permanent, but you have to get two more questions with the required score to earn one more badge (so you wont lose your badeges, but earning new ones will be harder)

Comment: @SztupY Not anymore. That was changed a while ago. You don't need to "make up" for it anymore.

Comment: @Mysticial Any reference? The wiki on the "FAQ" page still says you won't earn new badges

Comment: @SztupY I remember Nick Craver himself saying in a comment. So I don't even know where to begin to search aside from just asking him directly.

Comment: @Mysticial You mean this post?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119177/gaming-the-system-for-populist-badges/119221#119221 Here the wording is not really clear, and the community changelog for this is also not really helpful. (And this was in Jan 2012, and I remember not getting a badge last year because one of my badged answer was deleted)

Comment: @SztupY Yes, that's the one. And this is definitely the case. For example, [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo) has 84 answers with +10, but 87 Nice Answer badges. That would be impossible unless 3 of them were deleted most recently - which is not the case since his most recent +10 answer is not deleted.