# Where is my Populist badge?

Tags: support, badges, populist-badge

About few days ago, I've added an answer in Movies and TV SE. For this [Question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92247/).

In badge description, it says *Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times.* for badge **[Populist](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist)**. I'm not badge digger or something but curious. As for this moment, I've +84 votes(+85 and -1) while accepted answer has -23 votes (+5 and -28). and also my answer is the highest score (even regardless + or - status) while accepted has -23, mine has +84 and another answer has +12.

Is there something that I am missing? Why don't I have the badge yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer needs to have a score of more than ten.

Basically, if the accepted answer has a score of 11, your unaccepted answer will need to score 23 or higher to get the badge.  That's the minimum.

The accepted answer on your question has a score of -23, so it needs a few more up-votes until you get your badge.

Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh.. description on badge help have no such information on that.. Not gonna get badge for that question then anyways.. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes [there's been discussion on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188388/clarify-the-populist-badge-description).  But basically, when you finally understand how the badge works, you forget about the description.

Comment: Yeah, I even forgot about getting the badge, after seeing it.. :)

Comment: @Glorfindel 22 is the score on accepted answer, mine has 84

Comment: @snow Another thing, while accepted answer has -23 now, with only +5 what will happen if it gets +11 but still total score is ,minus?

Comment: It needs to have an "actual" score of 11 or more, not just 11 up-votes.  Hence the word "score" as opposed to "votes".