# Can you get Populist from your own question?

Tags: support, badges

The badge description for Populist is described as:

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x

I recently asked a question over on SFF and shortly afterwards found the answer myself and so answered my own question. A while later another answer was posted that came from a different source and was in my opinion better. As such at the time of writing my answer is +30 and the other is +14 and accepted. This would seem to qualify me for Populist but it has yet to come through (I know there is usually a delay with some badges).

Can I be awarded the Populist badge for an answer to my own question?

Comment: At one time it was possible, but [not anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119221/155839).